# Loading media files from a network drive in Django with Apache

Tags: python, django, apache, production-environment

I have a django page where I am trying to add a banner images which is stored in a network drive.

In Dev environment:

**setting.py** :

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = PureWindowsPath('//shared drive/folder/').drive

**urls.py**:

urlpatterns = [

```
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
......
......
```

]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

**models.py**:

class WelcomePage(models.Model):
departmentname = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
bannerimage = models.ImageField(upload_to='DjangoPortal/welcome/images/',blank=True)

**home.html**:

```
        <div class="card border-secondary mb-3">
            <div class="card-body" style="padding: 0px !important;">
                <img src="{{ pagedata.bannerimage.url }}" width="100%" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

with the above settings the page works perfectly

In Production:

All the above settings remains the same. In **settings.py** DEBUG =False and ALLOWED_HOSTS=[prod server ip, localhost]

In **httpd.conf** I added below

Define MEDIAROOT "//shared drive/folder/"

Alias /media "${MEDIAROOT}"

<Directory "${MEDIAROOT}">

Require all granted

</Directory>

but the image is not loading.
I am getting below error on Apache restart

**
AH00526: Syntax error on line 562 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf:
<Directory '//shared drive/folder/'> path is invalid.**

Am I doing anything wrong?

The technology specification is Windows Server 2012 R2 + Python 3.9 + Django 3.0.1 + SQL Server+ Apachelounge 2.4

Please guide if you have worked on or aware of this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the same settings in production like you did in you environnement dev.

MEDIA_ROOT = PureWindowsPath('//shared drive/folder/').drive

It should works.

have a good day

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort out the issue.

The issue was with the httpd.conf file

In httpd.conf the settings had to be changed to

Alias /media/ //shared drive/folder/

<Directory //shared drive/folder> - without " marks

Require all granted

</Directory>

and the apache service had to be started by a specific user without admin rights and having access to the share drive

Rest all the settings remain as mentioned above